# couchdb add a parameter on the view to get a document by id

Tags: couchdb

I have this view:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type && doc.type=='accounts') {
    emit( doc._id );
  }  
}
```

I can get a json with this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/crm/_design/accounts/_view/accounts-view?include_docs=true
```

my result is:

```
{"total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af","key":"8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af","value":null,"doc":{"_id":"8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af","_rev":"1-37eb3e76e4715e9a4fc8930470cc4ca3","type":"accounts","lastname":"Kitchen","firstname":"Peter"}},
{"id":"8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c","key":"8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c","value":null,"doc":{"_id":"8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058006e3c","_rev":"1-bcab94bb253c83b4951a787c253896f5","type":"accounts","lastname":"Kolner","firstname":"John"}},
{"id":"8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058008e9a","key":"8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058008e9a","value":null,"doc":{"_id":"8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b058008e9a","_rev":"1-86078f00be82b97499a0f52488cefbbf","lastname":"Tower","firstname":"George","type":"accounts"}}
]}
```

first question, why i have '_id' and 'key' fields ; both are the same.
second question,  when i add on the url a parameter to filter by id:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/crm/_design/accounts/_view/accounts-view?include_docs=true&id=8767d3474a0e80dd0ab7d0b0580065af
```

I get the same result, how must i to do for filter by the id, i think by id is special because the database is already indexed by id, but what about if i get filter by another field?

I know that every view consume space on disk, so i can resolve all my type of filters with one view and reduces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the **id** query parameter as you used is not valid. Refer to this [page](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/bulk-api.html) for the full list of query parameters.

Second, a view always emit 3 key.

- id
- key
- value

So if you build a view emitting the id, it's completely useless.

You might be asking : but why emitting the id and key?

Imagine a scenario where you build map/reduce on the phone number of every person. You will be able to get all the documents from a certain phone number. For indexing reason, you need to keep a link between the emitted values/keys with a document id. If you update the document, the view needs to be updated so without any id, that would be impossible.